# Import functions from dll (programmed in C++) into Python script when the dll has an embedded Python interpreter

Tags: python, python-c-api, python-extensions

I wrote a library (dll) in c++ that uses an embedded Python interpreter.
Executing Python scripts in the embedded interpreter works fine when the library is used by a c++ program.

If I call the functions of the dll from a Python program I run into trouble.
When the dll would usually start the embedded interpreter by calling Py_Initialize() there is an interpreter running already (I can test this by calling Py_IsInitialized() ).
When I try to use this interpreter the program crashes.

Minimal example that reproduces the behavior:

Code for dll:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Python.h>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
int testIsInitialized()
{
  return Py_IsInitialized();
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
void testRunSimpleString()
{
  PyRun_SimpleString("print('test')");
}
```

Python script:

```
import ctypes

dll=ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary('pytest.dll')

# test if Python interpreter is initialized
print(dll.testIsInitialized())

# test if we can run a simple Python script
dll.testRunSimpleString()
```

Output:

```
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_dll.py", line 9, in <module>
    dll.testRunSimpleString()
OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000000000010
```

My main question is:
How can I execute Python code from a c++ library that is imported by a different Python program?

**UPDATE**

The example works when I aquire the global interpreter lock (GIL) in my testRunSImpleString() function.
I do not understand why this is necessary here.

Comment: Sooooo you have a c++ with a python in it, and you now want to use that python from within another python? Why?

Comment: @Davesoft The dll should be usable from any programming language. Python is the special case where the dll does not work. I would prefer the execution of the embedded Python code in a separate interpreter. I am not sure how to achieve this. Maybe with a sub-interpreter? But the documentation for sub-interpreters is veryy thin.

Comment: Look at [`ctypes.PyDLL`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.PyDLL) - ctypes automatically releases the GIL and in your case this isn't helpful

Comment: @DavidW Thanks! That explains the behavior.

Answer (score 3):

The [**`ctypes`**](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) library has several classes to load different types of DLLs. Two relevant classes are:

- [`ctypes.CDLL`](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.CDLL) (i.e. C DLL) - used to load a DLL that uses a standard C calling convention. This includes C++ DLLs that define `extern "C"`.
- [`ctypes.PyDLL`](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.PyDLL) - similar to C DLL, except that the Python GIL is not released during the function call. Useful to call Python C API functions directly.

When loading a C++ DLL that uses the Python C API (i.e. `Python.h`), use `ctypes.PyDLL`:

```
import ctypes

dll = ctypes.PyDLL('pytest.dll')

# then do whatever
dll.testRunSimpleString.argtypes = []
dll.testRunSimpleString.restype = None
dll.testRunSimpleString()
```

One thing to keep in mind with PyDLL is to that you don't need to call `Py_Initialize()` or `Py_Finalize()`/`Py_FinalizeEx()` from the C++ API, since the interpreter is already running. You can first check (and store) `Py_IsInitialized()` to see if a new interpreter is need to be started/stopped.